# jquery mobile - force page update on ajax pull

Tags: php, jquery-mobile

My app currently changes data quite frequently and requires the user to switch back and forth between pages.

I often find that when a page is loaded through AJAX, and then you return to said page either through the backbutton, or by clicking a link...the information isn't always refreshed.

Is there a way to force this refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the fact that when you link pages through AJAX navigation in Jquery mobile they are automatically loaded into the DOM according to the documentation.

Try adding a data-dom-cache="false" to your "page" as one of the attributes.